Finding the mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium in this game
Find the pure and mixed-strategy Nash equilibrium in this game:
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
P_1 \text{/} P_2 & \text{Ll} & \text{Lr} & \text{Rl} & \text{Rr} \\
\hline
\text{T} & (3,2) & (3,2) & (1,1) & (1,1) \\
\text{B} & (4,3) & (2,4) & (4,3) & (2,4) \\
\end{array}

By using the definition of pure strategy Nash equilibria, I found these two Nash equilibria:
\begin{equation}
\text{Pure-strategy N.E.} = 
\begin{cases} 
([T],[Lr]) \\
([B],[Rr])
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
For the mixed-strategy Nash equilibria, it appears that the answer is:
\begin{equation}
\text{Mixed-strategy N.E.} = 
\begin{cases} 
([T], q[Ll] + (1-q)[Lr]) & \text{if } q < \frac{1}{2} \\
([B], q[Lr] + (1-q)[Rr]) & \text{if } q < \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
How would one derive the two mixed-strategy Nash equilibria?

First, note that there is a lot of weak domination:
$$Lr \succeq Ll, ~ Lr \succeq Rl, ~ Rr \succeq Rl, Ll \succeq Rl.$$
Consequently, $\nexists$ MSNE in which both players mix at the same time. If $P_1$ mixed, then $P_2$ would strictly prefer to play a pure strategy.
Consider then, as the answer suggests, a candidate equilibrium in which $P_1$ plays a pure strategy, whilst $P_2$ mixes.
If $P_1$ plays $T$, then $P_2$ is indifferent between $Ll$ and $Lr$.
$\implies$ $P_1 \to T, ~P_2 \to q(Ll) + (1 - q)Lr$. 
$P_2$ is indifferent by construction, so we need merely show that $P_1$ prefers $T$ to $B$:
$$\begin{align} 3 & \geq 4q + 2(1 - q) \\
& \geq 2 + 2q \\
1 &\geq 2q \implies 1/2 \geq q
\end{align}$$
Likewise, if $P_1 \to T$, then it must be that $P_2 \to q(Lr) + (1-q)Rr$.
Again, only need to show $P_1$ prefers $B$ to $T$:
$$\begin{align} 2 & \geq 3q + 1(1 - q) \\
1/2 & \geq q
\end{align}$$
This fully describes the Nash Equilibrium.

$Ll \succeq Lr$ is not true, it is the other way around? $Lr$ itself, however, is weakly dominant.

You're quite right, I'll edit.
